# Subscribers only receive a snippet of my post

Tags: sharing

How to set up sharing so that my email subscribers only get the first bit of a new post and must go to the site to read the entire post?

Answer (score 1):

If they're subscribed to your feed, go to Settings > Reading in wp-admin and where it says "For each article in a feed, show" choose "Summary" instead of "Full text."